# Name a list with a combination of previously defined variables in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a method that names a variable based on a specific set of other variables. For example, I want to create series of Lists (i.e., List1, List2, List3) by named according to two variables. For example:

```
string l = "List"
int += 1
```

Such that as I cycled through the code using a `foreach` loop it would name each List consecutively. Any ideas? I've only gotten this much "correct" so far and its not much:

```
public static string[] ListRenamer(List<string> list, int num)
{
    string x = list.ToString();
    string y = num.ToString();
    string[] z = new string[1];

    return z;
}
```

Comment: what is the reason behind this renaming lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` instead of separate lists here.
You can then name the keys according to your convention, and it can be done dynamically at runtime.
It is not possible to rename c# variables at runtime since c# is a static language